# Is it safe to reuse the same unused variable in nested loops?

Tags: lua

In some Lua script we have (in some Redis script, if that matters) we have constructs like this:

```
for _, user_id in ipairs(user_ids) do
    for _, product_id in ipairs(product_ids) do
        -- Do some things with user_id and product_id.
    end
end
```

The index in both loops is put in a variable `_` because we don't really care.

What I'm concerned about though is whether it is safe to reuse the same variable (even though it is not used) in nested loops or that leads to undefined behavior. Is it safe ?

Comment: Its not the same variable. Its a different un-named variable

Comment: @Arno: Sure it's a different variable but my question is more about: does it cause problems (scope, defined behavior) ?

Comment: Yes, there are two different variables.  Inner `_` variable is visible from inside the loop, outer `_` exists but invisible.  No problems if you don't care of their values.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks. I've done a lot of Python lately where the inner `_` would point to the same variable. I guess the key difference is that LUA for loops create scope while Python ones do not. That answers my question perfectly. Do not hesitate to post that as an answer. I'll happily accept it.

Comment: _ is not unnamed. It is a variable identifier just like any other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual [says](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5) explicitly that `for` loops are implicitly surrounded by `do ... end` blocks that contain the loop control variables as local variables.